# can't see the task manager in Windows 7 after opening it

Tags: windows-7

I recently unplugged my 2nd monitor so I could send it in for a refurb. Since I did that, when I start task manager, I can't find it. I think it's trying to put itself on the 2nd monitor. It doesn't show up in the system tray. I can't seem to use Alt space and M to move it back over, alt-space just opens the Windows menu.

Ideas for how to get this back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over the icon in the task bar so that the preview shows up, you can right click on the preview and select move. This will jump the mouse cursor to the title bar of the task manager. You can just left click and drag from there.

Comment: Sorry, I restarted and this problem went away. Don't know what the deal was but that fixed it.